# PHP - For statement creates a second empty element

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
include_once "removed.php";

$user = $conn -> real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM REMOVED WHERE removed ='$user' AND removed='1'";
$result = $conn -> query($query);

if(!$result){
  die($conn -> error);
}

else {
  $row = $result -> num_rows;

  for ($i = 0; $i < $row; ++$i)
  {
    $result -> data_seek($i);
    $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    ?>
    <h4><?= $row['Group_name'];?></h4>
    <?php
  }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

So this code that I have written has given me one issue it successfully creates the `<h4>` element with the $row data. However, it also creates an empty `<h4>` element as well.

Chrome inspector shows:

```
<h4> content that I want </h4>
<h4></h4>
```

I only have one entry in the database for test purposes.

Comment: Yes I was taking out important mysql query information. The whole file runs with the correct data.

Comment: I'd loop the `fetch` rather than creating your own `for`. I'd also just stay in the PHP and concatenate the `<h4>`s with an `echo`.

Comment: Do hoi have error_reporting enabled?

Comment: Im actually getting some of this code from the O'reilly php book, so I am unsure why this would have such could that produces a redundant element. Usually I would use a while statement.

Answer (score 1):

The "until" condition in your `for` loop is evaluated *each* iteration, including any variables used in it, such as `$row`. You're setting `$row` to `num_rows` outside your loop, and then you're overwriting that value inside the loop with `fetch_assoc`, causing your loop to continue past `num_rows`.

You must use a separate variable to maintain the number of rows and to load *each* row.

```
$num_rows = $result -> num_rows;

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; ++$i) {
  $row = ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was just typing this as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $row; ++$i)
  {
    $result -> data_seek($i);
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      ?>
      <h4><?= $row['Group_name'];?></h4>
      <?php
    }
  }
```

When I add the while statement it sorts the issue and only displays the one correct element. The second element does not load. Rather weird, as I still do not know how the for loop ended create the empty second element.

Comment: Lose the for loop

Comment: Your `while` loop increments until `$row` becomes `null`, at which point your `$i < $row` check in the *outer* loop fails. See my answer, you're trying to use `$row` to store to different values, and your inner use is clobbering your outer use.